# How to limit queries in ms access so that if data is not present in other fields, it will not show that entry?

Tags: ms-access

I have made a query with four fields, Site name, coarse stone, polished stone and flint. There are some sites that don't have any of these fields filled in, and I would like for the query to not show these sites. What I want the query to do is, 'If there is no data in any of the other three fields, then don't show the site'. I have tried typing 'Not Null' in all three of the other fields but then the query looks for a site that has data present in all three fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the query designer, it sounds like you have put the NOT NULL statement all in the same filter column, which generates and 'AND' clause for each of the fields.
Your query should be using an 'OR' statement, so the query should be something like
  SELECT [Site Name] FROM [Table Name] WHERE [Coarse Stone] IS NOT NULL OR [Polished Stone] IS NOT NULL OR [Flint] IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following structure:

```sql
SELECT MyField
FROM MyTable
WHERE NOT (Field1 Is Null And Field2 Is Null And Field3 Is Null)
```

Comment: Sorry, very new to access, Select MyField? from MyTable?

Comment: It's SQL, a basic query. This is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers. If you're not a programmer, try the Microsoft forum.